# Separating angular modules into components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I first had everything into one app.js but this is not a good approach. So I wanted to separate into different files, and I thought the best way would be making 3 different files (since I just have controllers and services).
The main entrance point app.js and then controllers.js and services.js
So after reading it is supposed to define the main module, and then use the others as dependencies, so I did it. But it isn't working.
Here are the file definitions:

app.js:

```
angular.module("personasApp", ["ngRoute", "personasApp.services", "personasApp.controllers"])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                controller: "ListController",
                templateUrl: "list.html",
                resolve: {
                    personas: function(Personas) {
                        return Personas.getPersonas();
                    }
                }
            })
            .when("/facturas/nueva", {
                controller: "CargarFacturaControlador",
                templateUrl: "facturas-form.html"
            })
            .when("/personas/nueva", {
                controller: "NuevaPersonaControlador",
                templateUrl: "contact-form.html"
            })
            .when("/personas/:personaId", {
                controller: "EditarPersonaControlador",
                templateUrl: "contact.html"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            })
      });
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module("personasApp.controllers", ["ngRoute"])
    .controller("ListController", function(personas, $scope) {
        $scope.personas = personas.data;
    });
    .controller("CargarFacturaControlador", function($scope, $location, Facturas) {
        $scope.atras = function() {
            $location.path("#/");
        }

        $scope.cargarFactura = function(factura) {
            Facturas.cargarFactura(factura).then(function(doc) {
                var facturaUrl = "/facturas/" + doc.data._id;
                $location.path(facturasUrl);
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
    })
    .controller("NuevaPersonaControlador", function($scope, $location, Personas) {
        $scope.atras = function() {
            $location.path("#/");
        }

        $scope.guardarPersona = function(persona) {
            Personas.crearPersona(persona).then(function(doc) {
                var personaUrl = "/personas/" + doc.data._id;
                $location.path(personaUrl);
            }, function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
        }
    })
    .controller("EditarPersonaControlador", function($scope, $routeParams, Personas) {
        Personas.getPersona($routeParams.personaId).then(function(doc) {
            $scope.persona = doc.data;
        }, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });

        $scope.toggleEdit = function() {
            $scope.editMode = true;
            $scope.contactFormUrl = "contact-form.html";
        }

        $scope.atras = function() {
            $scope.editMode = false;
            $scope.contactFormUrl = "";
        }

        $scope.guardarPersona = function(persona) {
            Personas.editarPersona(persona);
            $scope.editMode = false;
            $scope.contactFormUrl = "";
        }

        $scope.borrarPersona = function(personaId) {
            Personas.borrarPersona(personaId);
        }
    });
```

services.js

```
angular.module("personasApp.services", ["ngRoute"])
    .service("Facturas", function($http) {
        this.cargarFactura = function(factura) {
            return $http.post("/facturas", factura).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error cargando factura.");
                });
        }
    })
    .service("Personas", function($http) {
        this.getPersonas = function() {
            return $http.get("/personas").
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error intentando encontrar personas.");
                });
        }
        this.crearPersona = function(persona) {
            return $http.post("/personas", persona).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error creando persona.");
                });
        }
        this.getPersona = function(personaId) {
            var url = "/personas/" + personaId;
            return $http.get(url).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("No se pudo encontrar esta persona.");
                });
        }
        this.editarPersona = function(persona) {
            var url = "/personas/" + persona._id;
            //console.log(contact._id);
            return $http.put(url, persona).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error al editar esta persona.");
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
        this.borrarPersona = function(personaId) {
            var url = "/personas/" + personaId;
            return $http.delete(url).
                then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }, function(response) {
                    alert("Error al borar esta persona.");
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
    })
);
```

And from my index.html I use the script app.js

Comment: Define *"isn't working"*. What errors are you getting? Note-you really only need to inject `ngRoute` once. All injections are available throughout the whole app but that shouldn't cause it to fail

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, what the app should do is access to those forms via the route provider, but they aren't showing

Comment: ok...but that doesn't mention script errors thrown and you can also set up a route change error handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And from my index.html I use the script app.js

You definitely should include all files to HTML page, if you want to make them work. In case you added single files, your `services.js` and `controllers.js` just will not be executed.

Comment: I tried that also, but still the same. I only get this rendered when accessing the webpage but no displaying of the forms

Comment: You were correct, apparently I had a syntax error that when I opened the debugger for chrome I realized. Thanks